# Instagram Insight Webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, webhooks

Currently, I have a webhook subscribed to Instagram `story_insights` on my Facebook app. The Facebook app has a bunch of Facebook Business pages tied to Instagram Business accounts. Following the steps [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/webhooks) I have successfully set the webhook to work with test data from Facbeook; however, the webhook is never fired when a story ends/is deleted.

I am unsure how else to approach this. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? At first I thought it was because I hadn't called `subscribed_apps` for each account...but I did that and I'm still not seeing anything.

Comment: @Nizebulous no I never was able to resolve this issue. My team and I kind of moved passed this as a feature because no one could give us a straight answer.